# Need Windows Update detailed backgrounder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I really dislike the Windows Update service.

On the servers I manage, it continually consumes significant CPU and bandwidth, fills up storage in SoftwareDistribution which it never seems to release, and the updates often fail.

The progress feedback is appalling.  For a recent update, it sat on 0% for three hours, then 45% for another two hours, then 90% for another hour, then reported a failure, with a 32-bit error code.

I have really have enough of my time and server resources being wasted in this way, especially since "updates" are only needed to fix problems in faulty releases anyway.

Now to the point:  I have recently discovered the Microsoft Update Catalog, and I successfully installed the pending updates manually with much less friction.

So my intention is to disable the Windows Update service (this reduces background CPU activity from 40% to less than 5%, a real blessing) and simply install the critical updates manually when they become available.

So I want to get better acquainted with the update cycle and finding out which updates are due on which dates for my OS (Server 2016).  I'm already familiar with Patch Tuesday, but I want more detail on the release cycle of minor updates.

Also some background on dependencies between updates, I gather some require previous ones to already be in place.

Some kind of declaring historical listing would be great, but I haven't had much luck getting a detailed statement of this from anywhere.

Can someone point me to something helpful, ideally official?

Comment: This would be more helpful if you removed all that ranting and write the question with more facts (this will also reduce downvotes). Apart from that, there are alternate products available to install and manage updates, but product and service recommendations are off topic for this site, so I voted to close the question.

Comment: @Gerald, point taken.  Just trying to provide some background as to why I want an alternative solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you getting familiar with Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-server-update-services/get-started/windows-server-update-services-wsus.

Windows Server Update Services (WSUS) enables you to deploy the latest Microsoft product updates. You can use WSUS to fully manage the distribution of updates that are released through Microsoft Update to computers on your network. That means full control, deploy, postpone, or disable the update altogether.

It also allows you an excellent level of automation based on predefined policies that will enable you to install only the updates you need in the desired manner and within approved time frames.

Comment: uhm, that's exactly what the OP does NOT want to use.

Comment: Windows Update service and Windows Server Update Services are not the same. Windows Update is running on client machines while WSUS is a management system ruining on a server. You can use WSUS to install updates via PowerShell scripts without having Windows Update service running on a client machine.

Comment: Then you should point that out. Because that would exactly answer the question.

Comment: Thanks Net Runner, appreciate the suggestion, I wasn't aware of this service.  I will check it out, although I fear it might be another layer of overhead, perhaps it will provide more transparency.